# Merging GIT branches automatically in azure pipeline

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've GIT repo in Azure DevOps used in my pipelines.

This repo contains three branchs --> master (useless), PreProd and Prod

In pipeline I working on PreProd branch and after deployment I want to perform a task which merging the latest code in PreProd branch into a new commit in Prod.

So, is that possible and how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try API as @Tomasz suggested, or invoke git command to merge branches.

In addition, you could try `Create Pull Request` task to create a Pull Request and set Auto Complete:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I will try it.

Comment: Great it working well with 'Create Pull Request' Task, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think you are looking for this.

Comment: I tried this task but it access the repo with pat directly like git clone https://pat:***/url which it give an error unable to access the url, I think it should be accessed by base64 token

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason GitMerge task is not working for you, try calling Azure DevOps API for Git operations directly from script.

Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/merges/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has added functionality to run Git commands within pipelines.

[Run Git commands in a script - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/merges/create)

Their documentation also explains how to [Merge a feature branch to main](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#merge-a-feature-branch-to-main), which can easily be converted to work with two different branches such as `PreProd` and `Prod`.